# Alterar width coluna Modern UI MetroChart for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Bom dia pessoal.

Estou utilizando o MetroChart (https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/) para geração de gráficos, tudo está funcionando bem, porém eu gostaria de alterar o estilo das colunas / barras dos gráficos pois ele é configurado para ocupar todo o espaço do gráfico, e quando inserido apenas uma série acaba ficando com colunas / barras muito largas (width). Obs. Não consigo subir imagem pois estou no ambiente da empresa.

Baixei o código do link acima e estou tentando mexer no Generic.xaml para tentar encontrar onde seria essa alteração, mas até o momento não obtive sucesso.

Obrigado.

Comment: Pra variar, sempre somos preguiçosos para alguém.

Não vou me incomodar com o downvote pois essa pergunta é muito mais útil do que esse downvote inútil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiquei quebrando a cabeça nisso durante uma semana procurando em fórums e aqui no SO e agora fui dar uma olhada besta no próprio site e encontrei a resposta.

Não vou apagar a pergunta pois pode ser útil tanto para quem quer utilizar os gráficos quanto para quem está com o mesmo problema.

A resposta está aqui: https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/discussions/649398

O código para alteração é esse:

```
<chart:StackedColumnChart.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="chart:ColumnPiece">
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0" />
   </Style>
</chart:StackedColumnChart.Resources>
```